# jQuery reports no direct descendants of document

Tags: jquery, document, descendant

I'm using jQuery 1.6.1 at the moment.  In Firebug, I've seen that this:

```
console.log($(document).find("*"))
```

does what I expect;  it returns all the children of the document.  But this:

```
console.log($(document).find("> *"))
```

does not.  It returns an empty set!  It seems to me that, if the document has descendants, then it must have at least one direct descendant.  jQuery apparently disagrees.  Is this a bug, or a misunderstanding on my part?  Note also that this:

```
console.log($("body").find("> *"))
```

does what I expect, it returns direct descendants of the body tag.  Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: *Note: The `$("> elem", context)` selector will be deprecated in a future release. Its usage is thus discouraged in lieu of using alternative selectors.* **Source:** http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Comment: Interesting.  Do you know what will take its place?  There are times when it is critical to select only next-level descendants.

Comment: @dnuttle: You can always select children with the `.children()` method. And of course the selector `a > b` will work as before.

Comment: @dnuttle Select next-level descendants? You mean children? Hm, in that case maybe `.children()` `:p`

Comment: OK...duh.  Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document` has indeed (at least) one child, which is an `HTMLHtmlElement` (which inherits form `HTMLElement`), so yes, theoretically, jQuery(or Sizzle in this case) should return this one.

Is it a bug? It might be a design decision. But lets see what `$(document).children()` gives us:

```
alert($(document).children().length);
```

outputs `1`.

It is also interesting that `$(document).find("> html")` returns an empty set, whereas `$(document).find("html")` returns the `HTMLHtmlElement`. But the following is `true`:

```
$(document).find("html").parent()[0] === document
```

At least it is an inconsistency in jQuery. `.find('> *')` should return the same elements as `.children()` IMO.

It *may* be a bug in Sizzle or jQuery (someone with enough time can have a look at [Sizzle's source code *<sup>[source]</sup>*](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js) and find out where the problem could be).

On the other hand, one can say that the child selector only works on `Element` nodes, and `document` is not an `Element` node. From this point of view, there is no bug, just this inconsistency.